# gatsby graphql Cannot query field "allTribeEvents" on type "Query"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, graphql, gatsby

I am using gatsby with wordpress to display events from the events calendar API of wordpress . I am using the plugin `gatsby-source-tribe-events` to access the `allTribeEvents` graphql field . The problem is that if I have no events posted on wordpress the field `allTribeEvents` is not created and then if I run my graphql query on gatsby I get

```
Cannot query field "allTribeEvents" on type "Query"
```

So my problem is how to check if the field exists in graphql and query conditionally based on it .

My code :

React component to display events :

```
export default function Events() {
 
const data  = useStaticQuery(graphql`
   query EventsQuery {
    allTribeEvents {
      ...
     }
    }`);

//then I return my component based on the data 
}
```

So the point is that if no posts exist `"allTribeEvents"` is not created in grapqhl and I get an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my problem is how to check if the field exists in graphql and query
> conditionally based on it .

Short answer, you can't. Essentially because when you query something, you expect some result. The problem here is that because of the defined worfklow (WordPress -> Gatsby -> GraphQL node creation), the steps are broken.

The ideal solution in this cases, is to define a [Custom GraphQL Schema Definition](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/graphql-data-layer/schema-customization/) that will help you to tell Gatsby that the `allTribeEvents` can be `null`.

Another possible workaround (far less clean) is to create an empty tribe event (maybe with empty spaces or with some kind of defined field) and treat it in the front-end to avoid printing it (let's say you have an event named "-", if you find that field in the GraphQL query, filter it).